# Refining uninitialized variable in Flow

Tags: javascript, initialization, flowtype

How can I correctly do refinement on an uninitialized variable of a `?T` or `T|undefined` type?

What makes `uninitialized variable` different from a value of `undefined`?

Neither throws an error, however in the below case:

```
const test = (nums: Array<number>) => {
  let lastNumber: ?number
  const output = []
  if (lastNumber != null) {
    output.push(lastNumber /*lastNumber is Uncovered code*/)
  }
  return output
}
```

`flow type-at-pos` into `lastNumber` gives `(unknown)` because `uninitialized variable` (at declaration)

But this has full coverage:

```
const test = (nums: Array<number>) => {
  let lastNumber: ?number = undefined
  const output = []
  if (lastNumber != null) {
    output.push(lastNumber /*Fully covered*/)
  }
  return output
}
```

Comment: This is clearly a bug. Feel free to open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/flow

Comment: @NatMote https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4144 is this okay?
I didn't know if it was, since there isn't anything about uninitialized variables in the docs, and I only used flow for less than a day at that point. Thought that perhaps variables not explicitly initialized were discouraged.

Comment: Flow shouldn't allow incorrect code. The issue is that since it's uncovered you can actually pass it to anything and Flow will allow it. So, it's a soundness bug. Maybe uninitialized variables are discouraged but Flow should either disallow them or treat them soundly.